# Parser similar to Jericho HTML for .Net/C#

Tags: c#, .net, html, parsing

I have a Java app that uses the Jericho HTML Parser to walk HTML, replacing, modifying, etc nodes. I now need to do the same functionality in a .Net/C# app with the same HTML source. Can anyone recommend a good .Net library/package for this? I found "Html Agility Pack" which seems similar:

http://html-agility-pack.net

Any better ones I should be looking at? Thanks.,

Answer (score 4):

HTML Agility Pack seems to be the de-facto winner when looking for html manipulation libraries in .NET